# Batch For file loop String Replacement

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a few mp4 file in a directory, which was named by **wget**, an utility used to download files from the internet.

The thing is, it wrote filename as "**1%20-%201%20-%20Overview%20%2802%3A09%29.mp4**"(percent encoding of string "**1 - 1 - Overview (02:09)**"), which is a nuisance - it's not that straightforward. So I decided to use batch command to convert them.

As those files only contain a few special letters(space, colon and brackets), I thought I'd just execute a few commands in **cmd**, and after trying a few commands intended to change %20 to SPACE, I'm stuck.

In batch files, I'd use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
set aaa=%%i
rename "%%i" "!aaa:%%20= !"
)
```

and I've tried (for testing):

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %i in (*.mp4) do (
SET aaa="%i"
echo "!aaa:%%20= !"
)
```

I tried  changing '!' to '%', but it didn't work. It seems that it rather prints exactly what I wrote(like a few lines of **!aaa:%%20= !**), or the value of **aaa** doesn't change.

Can somebody help me? I thought just changing '%%' to '%' would convert a batch file script to cmd commands. What are other differences, if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is SETLOCAL does not work from the command line, so you never activate delayed expansion.

Also, you should put the quote before the variable being assigned so the quotes are not included in the value.

You can start a new cmd.exe shell with delayed expansion enabled to make things work.

```
cmd /v:on
FOR %i in (*.mp4) do (SET "aaa=%i"&echo "!aaa:%%20= !")
```

You need to be aware that you cannot change `%3A` to `:` because `:` is not valid in file names.

You might want to look into my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) that uses regular expression search and replace to rename files:

You could do something like:

```
jren "%20" " " /fm *.mp4
jren "%3A" "." /fm *.mp4
```

You would need to precede each command with CALL and double the percents if you use the above in a batch script.

Note that I converted `%3A` to `.` instead of `:` because the colon cannot be used in a file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=));""

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%i in (*.mp4) do (

  for /f %%N in (
  '%beginJS% decodeURIComponent("%%i") %endJS%'
  ) do set "dec=%%N"
  echo !dec!

)
```

What if you try decodeURIComponent from javascript (with mshta)  ?

Comment: I don't know anything about invoking Javascript in batch, and though it is surely a better way to handle my problem, I wanted to know the reason why my code didn't work.

Comment: @Namnamseo - in this case `%2` is taken as the second argument to the batch. And I think it won't with set..